# For the Brownian motion integrate

Tags: stochastic-calculus

I want to calculate 
$$\operatorname{E} \left[ \int_0^1{W(t)dt \cdot \int_0^1{t^2W(t)dt}} \right].$$

I discovered that the first integral is $\operatorname{N}(0, \frac{1}{3})$ but I don't know how to get the other one and the full answer of their multiplied expectation.

Answer (score 7):

Note that
\begin{align*}
E\left(\int_0^1 W_t\, dt \int_0^1 t^2W_t\, dt \right) &= E\left(\int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^1 s^2 W_s W_t\, dsdt \right)\\
&=\int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^1 s^2 E(W_s W_t)\, dsdt\\
&=\int_0^1\!\!\!\int_0^1 s^2 (s\wedge t)\, dsdt\\
&=\int_0^1 s^2\,ds \int_0^1 s\wedge t\, dt\\
&=\int_0^1 s^2\,ds \left(\int_0^s t\,dt + \int_s^1 s\,dt\right).
\end{align*}
The remaining is now straightforward.

Comment: Thank you very much. But the rest can be solved after that? Or just calculate 1/3(s^2/2+s-s^2)

Comment: The rest is just calculus.

Comment: @Gordon I guess you need to justify the first equality by Fubini.

Comment: @FunnyBuzer, yes, it is indeed based on Fubini.